# sinatra +Datamapper + mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby, sinatra, datamapper

I am using Sinatra and DataMapper with MySQL and i getting issues when i query the database.

My models.rb is the folloging:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'dm-core'
require 'dm-migrations/adapters/dm-mysql-adapter'

DataMapper::Logger.new("log/datamapper.log", :debug)
DataMapper.setup(:default, 'mysql://user:password@localhost/testdb')

class Item
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id,           Serial
  property :item,         String, :length => 50  

end

DataMapper.finalize
DataMapper.auto_upgrade!


Item.create(item:"item_one")
Item.create(item:"item_two")
```

The items are inserted in the database but when i query de database always returns nil values, example:

```
(rdb:1) @items =Item.all
[#<Item @id=nil @item=nil>, #<Item @id=nil @item=nil>]
```

if i query the numbers of items i get the expected result:

```
(rdb:1) @items.count
2
```

I have tried to make a query directly getting the same result :

```
adapter = DataMapper.repository(:default).adapt
adapter.select("SELECT * FROM items")
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or have suggestions on what to look for to fix problem?

Comment: The 1st code snippet is correct and creates two perfectly normal rows in database, with id-s 1 and 2. The devil is in the missing details: how do you get to the (rdb:1) prompt?

Answer (score 0):

Add these two lines to models.rb:

```
adapter = DataMapper.repository(:default).adapter
print adapter.select("SELECT * FROM items")
```

(Notice `.adapter`, not `.adapt`.) It prints

> [#<struct id=1, item="item_one">, #<struct id=2, item="item_two">]

Everything works as expected (ruby 2.1.7p400 (2015-08-18 revision 51632)).